# module reload on page refresh requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, require

modules loaded by requirejs are loading again on page refresh for e.g. Backbonejs and other js libraries. it should pick those modules from browser cache on page refresh . right ?

is there a way to implement this which will improve the performance to a great extent on page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files required par require.js are retrieved using the normal browser's mechanisms (as if you add done a ). In other words, if they can be cached, they'll be cached.

If you are using Chrome and DevTool is open, make sure in the options that you haven't checked "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"... there are probably similar options in Firefox / IE.

Comment: I agree with both comments but i have enabled caching in chrome and i am still seeing that all the modules are getting loaded again. To see that run [link](http://todomvc.com/dependency-examples/backbone_require/) and observer that modules will be loaded on page refresh.

Comment: There are no issue with the code. It's loaded from cache. See this screenshot: http://i.minus.com/ibx6tNCGRbZYoB.png

Answer (score 1):

As implied by @Enders, it's not strictly a RequireJS issue. All you can do is make sure your server sends correct response headers which will *encourage* your clients' browsers to cache the resources. I say "encourage" because there is no way to *force* clients to cache, in the worst case they could run with "disable all cache".

Approachable information about caching best practices can be found in [this Google Developers article](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching)